# Evaluating infinite series when the base index also goes to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $0 < a < 1$. It seems that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^{n}_{i=an}\frac{1}{i-1 } = -\ln ( a ) $$ though I am not sure if this result is correct. I believe the sum can be represented as an integral of $1/x$, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: There should be a $-$ sign in front of your rhs, and an integer part sign around $an$ in your lhs. After that, https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparaison_s%C3%A9rie-int%C3%A9grale#Principe_de_base gives you inequalities which prove your formula.

Comment: I wonder why the following comment was deleted. I rewrite it: thank you for having corrected the rhs. There remains to correct the lhs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define
$$S(x)=\sum_{ax\le i\le x}\frac1{i-1}$$
(as pointed in the comments, this is a more appropriate notation than your $\sum_{i=an}^n,$ since when $n$ is an integer, $an$ generally is not) and prove that
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}S(x)=-\ln a.$$

[Since the function $t\mapsto\frac1t$ is decreasing, for any positive integers $p\le q$ we have:](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparaison_s%C3%A9rie-int%C3%A9grale#Principe_de_base)
$$\ln\frac{q+1}p=\int_p^{q+1}\frac{dt}t\le\sum_{k=p}^q\frac1k\le\int_{p-1}^q\frac{dt}t=\ln\frac q{p-1}.$$
Therefore (for $x>\max(1,2/a)$ so that the fractions inside $\ln$ are $>0$)
$$\ln\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{\lceil ax-1\rceil}\le S(x)\le\ln\frac{\lfloor x-1\rfloor}{\lceil ax-2\rceil}$$
and *a fortiori*
$$\ln\frac{x-1}{ax}\le S(x)\le\ln\frac{x-1}{ax-2}.$$
By the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), the conclusion follows.